# Disable AutoCompleteExtender when '*' character exists

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a problem.

I am using AutoCompleteExtender for my textbox. All autocomplete words shows. But i need next behavior: when there is in textbox '*' character, autocomplete words must not be shown.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 5):

In your ServiceMethod you could check the string for the presence of the wildcard, and not return any results?

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count) {
  string[] results = null;
  if (string.IndexOf("*") == -1) {
    // Retrieve your autocomplete options here.
    // Create a new string[] and add the options.
  }
  return results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set DelimiterCharacters="*"

like

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender OnClientItemSelected="ace1_itemSelected" EnableCaching="true"
                                    DelimiterCharacters="*" EnableViewState="false" Enabled="true" UseContextKey="true"
                                    ServicePath="PurchaseOrderDetails.aspx" ServiceMethod="GetItemTypes" MinimumPrefixLength="1"
                                    CompletionInterval="100" CompletionListCssClass="AutoCompleteExtender_CompletionList"
                                    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoCompleteExtender_HighlightedItem"
                                    CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoCompleteExtender_CompletionListItem" CompletionSetCount="5"
                                    TargetControlID="txtItemTypeCode" ID="aceItemTypeCode" runat="server">
                                </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```